# How to mock rows in a Excel VSTO plugin?

Tags: c#, excel, unit-testing, vsto, moq

I am trying to put a mocked `Range` (which contains cells with values) inside the rows of a new `Range`. But when I try to access a specific element from the `Range`, a exception is thrown.

I've tried everything, does anyone have a idea what I am doing wrong here?

**Exception**

> Message: Test method xxx.MockUtilsTest.MockRowsTest threw exception: 
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot apply
>   indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Castle.Proxies.RangeProxy'

**Test**

```
[TestMethod]
public void MockRowsTest()
{
    var row1 = MockUtils.MockCells("test_row_1", "test_row_1");
    var row2 = MockUtils.MockCells("test_row_2", "test_row_2");
    var range = MockUtils.MockRows(row1, row2);

    Assert.IsNotNull(range);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, range.Count);
    Assert.IsNotNull(range.Rows);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, range.Rows.Count);
    Assert.AreSame(row1, range.Rows[1].Cells[1]); // exception is thrown here
    Assert.AreSame(row2, range.Rows[2].Cells[1]);
    Assert.AreEqual("test_row_1", range.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value2);
    Assert.AreEqual("test_row_2", range.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value2);
}
```

**MockUtils**

```
public static Range MockCellValue2(Object value)
{
    var cell = new Moq.Mock<Range>();
    cell.Setup(c => c.Value2).Returns(value);

    return cell.Object;
}

public static Range MockCells(params Object[] values)
{
    var cells = new Moq.Mock<Range>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        var cell = MockCellValue2(values[i]);
        cells.SetupGet(c => c[i + 1, Moq.It.IsAny<Object>()]).Returns(cell);
    }

    var row = new Moq.Mock<Range>();
    row.SetupGet(r => r.Cells).Returns(cells.Object);
    row.SetupGet(r => r.Count).Returns(values.Length);

    return row.Object;
}

public static Range MockRows(params Range[] rows)
{
    var mergedRows = MergeRanges(rows);
    var range = new Moq.Mock<Range>();
    range.SetupGet(r => r.Count).Returns(rows.Length);
    range.SetupGet(r => r.Rows).Returns(() => mergedRows);
    range.Setup(r => r.GetEnumerator()).Returns(rows.GetEnumerator());

    return range.Object;
}

public static Range MergeRanges(params Range[] ranges)
{
    var range = new Moq.Mock<Range>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ranges.Length; i++)
    {
        range.SetupGet(r => r[i + 1, Moq.It.IsAny<Object>()]).Returns(ranges[i]);
    }

    range.SetupGet(r => r.Count).Returns(ranges.Length);
    range.Setup(r => r.GetEnumerator()).Returns(ranges.GetEnumerator());

    return range.Object;
}
```

Comment: What does `MergeRanges(rows)` return?

Comment: @AlanT Sorry for my late response. I've added the method body of `MergeRanges` to my question. Please have a look.

Comment: @tomwassing try to use non static methods and class, declare your methods as virtual or implement/extract an interfance of your mock utils class and create your mock using the interface. Like: mock<InterfaceMockUtils>();

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The indexer of `Range` returns a dynamic object, this is the source of your problem.

[image]

Moq use `Castle Dynamic proxy` to generate fake objects, `Castle.Proxies.RangeProxy` is the generated class in your case. Since this object is not a `COM` object the processing of those the C# Runtime binder is being called. The Runtime binder resolves the type and looking for the indexer method, but he failed to resolve it because the generated class don't have it.

The easiest way to solve your is to return the indexer result to a strict `Range` local variable:

[image]

Then your test will fail because `range.Rows[1]` is equals to `row1`...

So change your test code to:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MockRowsTest()
{
    var row1 = MockUtils.MockCells("test_row_1", "test_row_1");
    var row2 = MockUtils.MockCells("test_row_2", "test_row_2");
    var range = MockUtils.MockRows(row1, row2);

    Assert.IsNotNull(range);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, range.Count);
    Assert.IsNotNull(range.Rows);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, range.Rows.Count);
    Range x = range.Rows[1];
    Range y = range.Rows[2];
    var xCell = x.Cells[1];
    var yCell = y.Cells[1];
    Assert.AreSame(row1, x); 
    Assert.AreSame(row2, y);
    Assert.AreEqual("test_row_1", xCell.Value2);
    Assert.AreEqual("test_row_2", yCell.Value2);
}
```

The above UT will pass the test. IMO you should to break your aggregation calls to "atomic OPS(multi line) and methods" not because it will pass the test, because it will make your code a debug friendly code.(I call that "the 11TH rule" where your code will be read a least 10 more times from the time it was written... So let the compiler to remove the transitive local variables and make your it a debug friendly code..).

[Here you can read a simple and short explanation with links on how dynamic works in c#.](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/interviews/show/6543/how-dynamic-works-in-csharp-40)

[Here you can read more about Castle Dynamic Proxy.](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy-introduction.md)

BTW; you also can do:

```
Range x = range.Rows[1].Cells;
var str = x[1].Value2;
```

to receive the value