# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Castle.Proxies.RangeProxy'

Tags: c#, excel, unit-testing, mocking, moq

What is causing this exception? I am trying to use `Moq` to mock a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range`. I want to nest another mocked `Range` inside it. But when I try to access the nested exception, a exception is thrown.

**Exception**

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   'Castle.Proxies.RangeProxy'

**Code**

```
[TestMethod]
public void RangeProxyIndexTest()
{
    // creating first range
    var cell1 = new Moq.Mock<Range>();
    cell1.Setup(c => c.Value2).Returns("1");

    var range1Mock = new Moq.Mock<Range>();
    range1Mock.SetupGet(r => r[1, Moq.It.IsAny<Object>()]).Returns(cell1.Object);
    var range1 = range1Mock.Object;

    // creating second range
    var cell2 = new Moq.Mock<Range>();
    cell2.Setup(c => c.Value2).Returns("2");

    var range2Mock = new Moq.Mock<Range>();
    range2Mock.SetupGet(r => r[1, Moq.It.IsAny<Object>()]).Returns(cell2.Object);
    var range2 = range2Mock.Object;

    // merging both ranges into 1
    var range3Mock = new Moq.Mock<Range>();
    range3Mock.SetupGet(r => r[1, Moq.It.IsAny<Object>()]).Returns(range1);
    range3Mock.SetupGet(r => r[2, Moq.It.IsAny<Object>()]).Returns(range2);
    var range3 = range3Mock.Object;

    // testing succeeds
    Assert.AreEqual("1", range1[1].Value2);
    Assert.AreSame(range1, range3[1]);
    Assert.AreEqual("2", range2[1].Value2);
    Assert.AreSame(range2, range3[2]);

    // exceptions are thrown here
    Assert.AreEqual("1", range3[1][1].Value2);
    Assert.AreEqual("2", range3[2][1].Value2);
}
```

Comment: Maybe because `range3` *is not* a two-dimensional array?

Comment: @Rafalon `[][]` is no the syntax of two-dimensional array in `c#` (in `java` `[][]` is two-dimensional array) in `c#` it is an aggregating indexers call, which is the source of the OP's problem... the first indexer returns a dynamic type then the Runtime Binder couldn't evaluate the second indexer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the situation is different, the reason to this exception is exactly the same as the [other question you have opened.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50524000/4332059)

Change your verification part to:

```
Assert.AreEqual("1", (range3[1] as Range)[1].Value2);
Assert.AreEqual("2", (range3[2] as Range)[1].Value2);
```

For more information read [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50651490/4332059)